# Wx.Widgets AUIMananger Toggle Panes

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm having trouble toggling panes with the AUIManager.

Here's basically what I'm doing:

```
class foo(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,wx.ID_ANY,title,size=wx.Size(800,600))
        self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()

        self._mgr = wx.aui.AuiManager(self)
        self._mgr.AddPane(self.randomwidget, wx.LEFT, 'Widget Name')
        self._mgr.Update()

        self.menu_view = wx.Menu()
        self.menu_view_randomwidget = wx.MenuItem(self.menu_view,wx.ID_ANY, 'Widget Name', kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        self.menu_view.AppendItem(self.menu_view_randomwidget)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.togglePane, id=self.menu_view_randomwidget.GetId())
        self.menubar.Append(self.menu_view, '&View')

    def togglePane(self,event):
        if self._mgr.GetPane('Widget Name').IsShown():
            self._mgr.GetPane('Widget Name').Hide()
        else:
            self._mgr.GetPane('Widget Name).Show()
        print self._mgr.GetPane('Widget Name').IsOk()
```

This always results in a  'False' output.  Is there a more appropriate way to toggle various aui panes?

Comment: FYI: There's also a pure Python implementation of the AUI stuff in the agw generic widget set. It's a little more advanced than the default AUI stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This method works fine for me. It should for you too if you call `Update()` on your `window manager` after you show or hide your pane.

```
 def togglePane(self,event):
     if self._mgr.GetPane('Widget Name').IsShown():
         self._mgr.GetPane('Widget Name').Hide()
     else:
        self._mgr.GetPane('Widget Name).Show()
        print self._mgr.GetPane('Widget Name').IsOk()
     self._mgr.Update()#<--------------It should work if you add this line
```